# Location of roots for a special class of polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$

Tags: polynomials, roots

I am reading "Prime numbers and Irreducible Polynomials" by M. Ram Murty published in American Mathematical Monthly 2002. I have a question on a result which is as follows

*Statement:*

Let $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ belong to $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Suppose that $a_n\ge1, \ a_{n-1}\ge 0 \ $ and $|a_i|\le H$ for $i=0,1,...,n-2,$ where $H$ is some positive constant. Then any complex zero $\alpha$ of $f(x)$ either has $\mathfrak{R}(\alpha)\le 0$ or satisfies
$$
|\alpha| < \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4H}}{2} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$

*Proof:*

If $|z|>1$ and $\mathfrak{R}(z)>0$ we observe that
$$
\left|\frac{f(z)}{z^n}\right| \ge \left|a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{z}\right|-H\left(\frac{1}{|z|^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{|z|^n}\right)
$$
$$
>\mathfrak{R}\left(a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{z}\right)-\frac{H}{|z|^2-|z|}
$$
$$
\ge 1-\frac{H}{|z|^2-|z|} = \frac{|z|^2-|z|-H}{|z|^2-|z|} \ge 0
$$
whenever
$$
|z| \ge \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4H}}{2} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \                (2)
$$
Consider an arbitrary complex zero $\alpha$ of $f(x)$. If $|\alpha|\le 1$ then (1) holds trivially. Now suppose that $|\alpha|>1$, Either $\mathfrak{R}(z)\le 0$ or $(2)$ must fail for $z=\alpha$, since $\left|\frac{f(z)}{z^n}\right|$ is positive whenever $\mathfrak{R}(z)>0$ and (2) holds.

Thus either $\mathfrak{R}(z) \le 0$ or $\alpha$ satisfies (1).

---

My question:

1. How is this inequality obtained?
   $$
   \left|\frac{f(z)}{z^n}\right| \ge \left|a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{z}\right|-H\left(\frac{1}{|z|^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{|z|^n}\right)
   $$
2. How to obtain this inequality?
   $$
   \left|a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{z}\right|-H\left(\frac{1}{|z|^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{|z|^n}\right)
   >\mathfrak{R}\left(a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{z}\right)-\frac{H}{|z|^2-|z|}
   $$
3. We are using the assumptions $a_n \ge 1$ and $a_{n-1} \ge 0$ to obtain the inequality:
   $$
   \mathfrak{R}\left(a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{z}\right)-\frac{H}{|z|^2-|z|}
   \ge 1-\frac{H}{|z|^2-|z|}
   $$
   Can we weaken the restrictions on $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$?

---

Edit:

Following Kooranifar's  answer I have done the following:

1. $$ \left| \frac{f(z)}{z^n}\right| -  \left|a_n + \frac{a_{n-1}}{z}\right| \le \left|\sum\limits_{i=2}^n \frac{a_{n-i}}{z^{i}}\right|$$
   But for the inequality to hold we need
   $$
   -\left|\sum\limits_{i=2}^n \frac{a_{n-i}}{z^{i}}\right|
   $$
   in the inequality. How to obtain it?
2. 

$$
\left|a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{z}\right| \ge \mathfrak{R}\left(a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{z}\right)
$$
This part comes from $|\alpha| \ge \mathfrak{R}(\alpha)$

Now for the part containing $H$ we need to establish
$$
H\left(\frac{1}{|z|^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{|z|^n}\right)
<\frac{H}{|z|^2-|z|}
$$
We see that
$$
H\left(\frac{1}{|z|^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{|z|^n}\right)
=
H\left(\frac{|z|^{n-2}+\cdots+1}{|z|^n}\right)
=
H\left(\frac{|z|^{n-1}-1}{|z|^n(|z|-1)}\right)
$$
$$
=H\left(\frac{1}{|z|(|z|-1)}-\frac{1}{|z|^n(|z|-1)}\right)
$$
$$
< H\left(\frac{1}{|z|(|z|-1)}\right)
$$

Comment: on the third line of the statement, is $\mathfrak{R}(z)$ meant to be $\mathfrak{R}(\alpha) $?

Comment: The assumption $a_n \geq 1$ is not really a restriction on $f(x)$: because you let $f(x)$ to be $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$, you've already assumed that $ a_n \neq 0 $, so because $a_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $ |a_n| \geq 1$. also note that if $ a_n \leq -1 $, you can take $ g(x) = - f(x)$ which has the largest coefficient $ - a_n \geq 1 $; $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ has the same set of roots, so any statement about roots of each of these, holds or does not hold at the same time for both.

Comment: @Kooranifar Thank you for pointing out the mistake. I have changed it to $\alpha$.

Comment: @Kooranifar Then can we say that the only restriction is $a_{n-1}\ge 0$? As we can always get a desired $H$ for any polynomial by choosing $H=max\{|a_{n-2}|,\cdots,|a_1|,|a_0|\}$.

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: @Kooranifar Can you tell me how to obtain the inequalities in questions 1. and 2. ?  Any hints will also do.

Comment: I'm writing you an answer, and will make it available as soon as my TeX-typing speed lets; up to half an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to mention the discussion in the comments that we had, because I think it might has gone a bit wrong: as we've said the assumption $ a_n \geq 1 $ itself need not put a restriction on $f(x)$ because of the $g(x)$ argument that I made in the comments; but notice that for $g(x) = -a_nx^n-a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots-a_1x-a_0$ the sign of second largest coefficient also flips. So eventually, the restrictions on $f(x)$ really mean that $a_{n-1}$ is zero or it has the same sign as $ a_n $. About your questions I would provide some hints; but if it isn't sufficient, feel free to ask for elaboration.

1. note that $$ \sum_{i=2}^{n} \frac{|a_i|}{|z|^{n-i}} \leq  \sum_{i=2}^{n} \frac{H}{|z|^{n-i}} \tag{1} $$
   So by triangle inequality for left hand, and then multiplying sides by $-1$ we have
   $$ -|\sum_{i=2}^{n} \frac{a_i}{z^{n-i}}| \geq  \sum_{i=2}^{n} \frac{-H}{|z|^{n-i}} \tag{2} $$
   Now for the questioned inequality to hold, it suffices to show that $$ | f(z) / z^n | -  | a_n + \frac{a_{n-1}}{z} | \geq -|\sum_{i=2}^{n} \frac{a_i}{z^{n-i}}| \tag{3} $$ Hint for this: you may somewhere need to use: $  |a| - |b| \leq |a-b|  \tag{4}$

---

**More elaboration as requested:**

Let's show $(3)$; taking $ | a_n + \frac{a_{n-1}}{z} | $ as $ |a| $, and $ | f(z) / z^n |$ as $|b|$ and applying $(4)$, we will get

\begin{align}
|a_n + \frac{a_{n-1}}{z}| - |\frac{f(z)}{z^n}| &\leq  | a_n + \frac{a_{n-1}}{z} - \frac{f(z)}{z^n}| \\
&= | - \frac{a_{n-2}}{z^2} - \frac{a_{n-3}}{z^3} - \cdots - \frac{a_0}{z^n}| \\
&= | \frac{a_{n-2}}{z^2} + \frac{a_{n-3}}{z^3} + \cdots + \frac{a_0}{z^n}| \\
\end{align}

and by multiplying sides by $-1$ we get $(3)$. Notice that the right hand side of $(3)$ and left hand side of (2) are the same, so combining $(2)$ and $(3)$ will result in inequality 1.

2. Note that for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$ we have $ |z| \geq \mathfrak{R}(z) $. For the terms containing $ H $, as a hint, multiply sides by $ |z|^n $ and take a look at what happens. The fact that $ |z| > 1 $ shows why the whole inequality is a $ > $ and not a $ \geq $.
3. As you correctly said, the assumptions on coefficients are needed in this inequality. More specifically, for showing that
   $$ \mathfrak{R}\left(a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{z}\right) \ge 1 $$
   in the following way: Since $ \mathfrak{R}(z) > 0 $ and real parts of $z$ and $\frac{1}{z}$ have the same sign, we also have $\mathfrak{R} ( \frac{1}{z} ) > 0$ and by that,
   $$ \mathfrak{R}\left(a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{z}\right) = a_n + a_{n-1} \mathfrak{R}(\frac{1}{z}) \geq 1 + 0 = 1 $$
   following our discussion in the comments, assuming that $ a_n \geq 1 $, if $ a_{n-1} $ was negative, I don't see an easy way to deduce this last inequality; But maybe others could.

Comment: I have followed your steps for proving the inequality 1. but  I am having trouble obtain the desired inequality. I have added myworkings into the question.

Comment: @Saikat That's ok, I will elaborate on first inequality, in 2 hours

Comment: @Saikat Sorry for being tardy; I edited my answer on inequality 1. I didn't write a proof for $(2)$ but if it's needed, let me know.

Comment: Can you please help me write a proof for (2)? I am again stuck thinking it's proof. Thank you.

Comment: @Saikat yeah sure; could you tell me where exactly it runs into problem?

Comment: I have added my tryings in the edit portion. If you check and tell if the line of arguments are ok or not. Then it will be very helpfull.

Comment: @Saikat Uh yes, I didn't notice. I thoroughly agree with what you've done.